# Logic & Negation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

(A) Consider the statement $\forall x \exists y \lnot P(x, y)$. Write down a negation of the statement that does not use the symbol $\lnot$.

I just said that its $\forall x \exists y P(x, y)$ but I'm not entirely sure. Can someone clarify?

(B) Under the interpretation where $x$ and $y$ are in $\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \{0\}$ and $P(x, y)$ is "$xy ≥ 0$", is the original
statement in (B) true or is its negation true?

For this part, I said when $x$ and $y$ are BOTH positive or negative integers, then (B) is true, but when one is positive and the other is negative, then the negation is true? Am I on the right track?

Comment: Concerning B you must wonder: "is $\forall x\exists y\neg P(x,y)$ a true statement in this context?" If so then you choose for "original" as answer. If not then you choose for "negation of original" as answer.

Answer (score 5):

A)

Wrong.

Step by step we find that the following are negations of $\forall x\exists y\neg P(x,y)$

- $\neg\forall x\exists y\neg P(x,y)$
- $\exists x\neg\exists y\neg P(x,y)$
- $\exists x\forall y\neg\neg P(x,y)$
- $\exists x\forall yP(x,y)$

In the last one $\neg$ is not present.

B)

The original statement is true.

For every $x\in\mathbb R-\{0\}$ we can find an $y\in\mathbb R-\{0\}$ such that $xy<0$. We can take $y=-x$.

Comment: Is (b) correct or also wrong wrong because (a) was wrong?

Comment: @Okie Your answer to (b) is not even wrong. The answer required should be just "the statement in A is true" or "the negation of the statement in A is true".

Answer (score 0):

(A) The negation of sentences is 
$\exists x\forall y  $ $P(x,y)$

(B) when you interpret the sentence in $\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ you have that $\forall x\exists y  $ $P(x,y)$ because for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ exists $y=-x$ such that $\neg (xy>0)$